# Logging ASMX Requests and Responses from Client

Tags: web-services, logging, asmx

I've got a C# web application which I can't easily update the code of. However, I can make configuration changes to the application.

The application calls out to a third-party ASMX web service, and I really need (if at all possible) to log the full XML requests and responses. I have no control over the web service so I have to do it from the client.

I'm not using WCF - this is standard ASMX web service calls.

Is there any way I can log the XML requests and responses from the client web app without having to redeploy the code?

Thanks in advance

John

Comment: @John: if you can use "Add Service Reference" to create a WCF client, then you can trivially turn on tracing and message logging.

Comment: Thanks very much John.

I couldn't use WCF as this would have meant changing the client application considerably. However the SoapExtension option worked perfectly and I got the information I needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about Tracing for Web Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb885203(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this without changing the application. You might get away with creating a [SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) as a separate binary, then storing it in the `\bin` folder and changing the web.config to point to it. Still, adding a new binary may very well be considered "changing the application".

Certainly, ASMX has no configurable logging that does not require coding.